# WordPress themes and plugins development

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to develop WordPress  themes and plugins. What do I need to know to do this?

I have knowledge of PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I have developed a few projects using these. What is the best place to start (except Codex), is there any book? Where can I know how the core of WordPress works?

Comment: What's wrong with Codex and have you tried Googling?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with codex, I just want to know what are the alternatives. People here knows so much, I just want them to share their knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Professional WordPress Plugin Development](http://amzn.to/mo2Vew)
2. [Digging into WordPress](http://goo.gl/6ReeM)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this neat infographic for a good introduction to the anatomy of a wordpress theme.

http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

Answer (score 0):

For Plugins: 
There are two places where you can code for plugin in Wordpress. 
1. `functions.php`
2. Create a folder in plugins folder, inside that folder. Create a blank `.php` file, and code there.

For Themes: 
As you asked for learning wordpress themes. 
Go to themes folder, try to get the structure and flow of wordpress default themes.
You've to code within themes folder.